# ¿Cómo utilizar variables creadas en typescript, en el html?

Tags: angular

estoy trabajando un proyecto en angular, pero no se como hacer para poder llamar las variables del TS en el html. ya hice la conección entre ambos documentos, sin embargo, al llamar la variable me escribe es el nombre de la variable como si fuera texto.

////////////////////////////////////
CÓDIGO TYPESCRIPT
///////////////////////////////////

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 
    console.log("creandose") 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("creado")
  }

  nombre = "arvey"  

}
```

///////////////////////////////
CÓDIGO HTML
///////////////////////////////

```
<div>{{nombre}}</div>
```

//////////////////////////////
RESULTADO EN LA PAGINA
///////////////////////////////
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para ayudarte, necesitamos más detalles acerca de cómo hiciste esa "conexión" entre ambos "documentos". Si puedes compartirnos ese código con gusto te ayudo.

Comment: En la imagen se ve que intentas acceder a la ruta del `template`, no es lo usual en Angular. Deberías tener un servidor que te muestre tu componente en la ruta raíz, no como lo tienes actualmente.

Comment: amigo la conexión se hizo por defecto, es decir, yo cree el proyecto por medio de consola, las conexiones ya venían hechas, yo solo creé una variable en el typescript y la llamé en el html (ambos documentos son del mismo componente). A su vez cree otro proyecto nuevo sin cambiar nada para ver que había hecho mal, y sigue pasando lo mismo, en la pagina de prueba que crea el proyecto tampoco toca las variables. Hay un titulo en la pagina de prueba que en vez de mostrar el valor de la variable, muestra {{ titulo }}. Por cierto el html es  (/header.component.html), con ese alias hago conecto el ts

Comment: ¿el html en que archivo está? ¿Qué versión de angular usas?¿Usas el router?¿Cómo tienes la configuración de tu módulo?